# typescript Response.json()で引数に関するエラー(2554)

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

app.use(bodyParser());

app.post("/product", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  let product = {
    test: "test"
  }
  res.json(product)
})
```

> res.json(product)

の部分で以下のエラー`2554`が発生してしまいます。
このエラーを回避する方法はありますか？

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
```

`json()`の定義元である`lib.dom.d.ts`で、`json()`の引数がそもそも定義されていないので、
良い解決方法を見つけられませんでした。

```
interface Body {
    readonly body: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null;
    readonly bodyUsed: boolean;
    arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
    blob(): Promise<Blob>;
    formData(): Promise<FormData>;
    json(): Promise<any>;
    text(): Promise<string>;
}
```

> json(): Promise;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expressが提供する型情報を参照していないようです。

Requestは確かに`lib.dom.d.ts`にありますが、expressが提供する型情報は[@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express)を参照する必要があります。

そのためには以下のように書き直すと良いでしょう。

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.post("/product", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  let product = {
    test: "test"
  }
  res.json(product)
})
```